# Error in XPath binding in XAML

Tags: xml, xaml, xpath

I have a binding in XAML:

```
{Binding XPath=List/Item[@Status='OK']}
```

Visual Studio tells me it's expecting ' and } but when I look at documentation elsewhere, it seems this line looks fine. It won't compile and gives me an error saying that the member List/Item[@Status='OK'] is not accessible.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To fix the problem, try to escape the entire XPath expression with quotes, and escape quotes inside XPath using `&amp;amp;amp;quot;` :

```
{Binding XPath='List/Item[@Status=&amp;amp;amp;quot;OK&amp;amp;amp;quot;]'}
```

Or another option, escape equals sign and single quotes using backslash :

```
{Binding XPath=List/Item[@Status\=\'OK\']}
```

References :

- [XPATH equality expression value in XAML Errors (С#, WPF)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3090614/xpath-equality-expression-value-in-xaml-errors-wpf)
- http://blogs.msdn.com/b/karstenj/archive/2006/05/30/611127.aspx

Comment: I get the error 'The named entity &quote;' is not defined in xaml

Comment: Ah there is a typo in your post, it should be &quot;