# Binding WPF treeview to nested xpath with contains filter

Tags: c#, xml, wpf, xpath, treeview

I'm trying to create a WPF treeview based on the output from an xpath query.  The idea is that, based on a search string, a treeview representing a tiny subset of a very large xml document will be presented. WPF and xpath are totally new to me (couple of weeks) so possibly a dumb question...

In a console application, this works fine and gives exactly what I want as a basis for the tree.

```
XmlNodeList nodeList = root.SelectNodes("//item[not (item) and contains(name, 'kidney')]//ancestor::item");

foreach (XmlNode node in nodeList)
{
    file.WriteLine($"{node.ChildNodes[0].InnerText}");

    //Console.WriteLine($"{node.Name} -  {node.InnerText}");
}
```

However, when I use the same xpath in a binding as follows:

```
ItemsSource="{Binding Source={StaticResource xmlDataProvider}, XPath=//item[not (item) and contains(name, 'kidney')]//ancestor::item}"
```

I get a bunch or errors around the construction of the xpath piece (xpath = /* works fine).  I thought it might be the single quotes but replacing with the XML special character or escaping with \ makes no difference. At this stage I'm wondering if nested xpath statements can be used at all?

Comment: Do it the easy way.  Don't use bind, instead just add the items int a treeview.  Use your console code, but instead of using WriteLine() add strings to a treeview.

Comment: Ah...  All of the examples I've looked use binding in the xaml.  If I'm understanding you the treeview can be managed in c# code?  That would suit me much better so I'll research that.  Thanks a lot.

Comment: See following webpage : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28976601/recursion-parsing-xml-file-with-attributes-into-treeview-c-sharp.  The code recursively puts an entire xml file into a treeview but you can modify the code as required.

Comment: Thanks, I'll try that over the weekend

Answer (score 0):

Try to escape `'` in your XPath binding-parameter as follow :

```
XPath=//item[not(item) and contains(name, \'kidney\')]//ancestor::item
```

Similar problem : [Error in XPath binding in XAML](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23131068/error-in-xpath-binding-in-xaml/23131376#23131376)

Comment: Hi and thanks - I have already tried that with no success (actually I believe based on the issue you linked)

Comment: I believe so but will check this later, thanks again.